# How to toggle show and hide password for multiple field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I want to toggle the show and hide password for the input fields.

It can work on single input, but I don't know how to do it for multiple input field

I want that on clicking input icon it will toggle for the show/hide password

It should work individually for each input field.

for example if I click on current password input field icon then it will only show/hide password for this input field.

```
const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    password: "",
    showPassword: false,
  });
  
  const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    setValues({ ...values, showPassword: !values.showPassword });
  };
  
  const handlePasswordChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };
  
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        marginLeft: "30%",
      }}
    >
      <h4>Change your password</h4>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
        Current password
      </InputLabel>
      <Input
        type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
        onChange={handlePasswordChange("password")}
        value={values.password}
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton
              onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
            >
              {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
            New password
        </InputLabel>
        <Input
            type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
            onChange={handlePasswordChange("password")}
            value={values.password}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
            Confirm password
        </InputLabel>
        <Input
            type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
            onChange={handlePasswordChange("password")}
            value={values.password}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like that ?

```js
const Input = (props) => {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"} {...props} />
      <button onMouseDown={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setShowPassword(!showPassword)
      }}>{showPassword ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} password</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const reducer = (state, changes) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    ...changes
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useReducer(reducer, {
    currentPassword: "",
    newPassword: "",
    confirmPassword: ""
  });
  
  
  return (
    <div style={{ marginLeft: "30%" }}>
      <h4>Change your password</h4>
      <label htmlFor="current-password">Current password</label>
      <Input id="password-input" onChange={({target}) => {
        return setValues({currentPassword: target.value})
      }} />
      
      <label htmlFor="new-password">New password</label>
      <Input id="new-password" onChange={({target}) => {
        return setValues({newPassword: target.value})
      }} />
      
      <label htmlFor="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
      <Input id="confirm-password" onChange={({target}) => {
        return setValues({confirmPassword: target.value})
      }} />
      
      <h4>Form content</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>currentPassword : {values.currentPassword}</li>
        <li>newPassword : {values.newPassword}</li>
        <li>confirmPassword : {values.confirmPassword}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand.. where do you implement handleClickShowPassword ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove handleClickShowPassword() and handlePasswordChange(), they were actually useless in my example. Instead of using these functions I handle password change inside `onChange` prop of each <input> and to show the password I put a function inside the `onMouseDown` prop of the show password <button> (inside the <Input /> component).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using one `boolean` to check 3 fields `password`. To fix, you just update `showPassword` to store `string` like this:

```
  const handleClickShowPassword = (fieldName) => {
    setValues({ ...values, showPassword: fieldName === values.showPassword ? "" : fieldName});
  };

...
type={values.showPassword === "currentPassword" ? "text" : "password"}
onClick={() => handleClickShowPassword("currentPassword")}
{values.showPassword === "currentPassword" ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
...

...
type={values.showPassword === "newPassword" ? "text" : "password"}
onClick={() => handleClickShowPassword("newPassword")}
{values.showPassword === "newPassword" ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
...

...
type={values.showPassword === "confirmPassword" ? "text" : "password"}
onClick={() => handleClickShowPassword("confirmPassword")}
{values.showPassword === "confirmPassword" ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it's giving error at " fieldName === showPassword ". Can not find name showPassword

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean `values.showPassword`. I updated my answer

Comment: Hey thanks, the error has gone, but when I click on icon for toggle nothing is happening. By default it's showing type as a text and visibility off icon

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with this. Let me know if it helps

```js
const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    currentPassword:{show:false,password:'' "},
    newPassword:{show:false,password:'' "},
    confirmPassword{show:false,password:'' "}
  });

const handleClickShowPassword = (prop) =>{
    Input = values[props]
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: {show:!Input.show, password:Input.password} });
  };
  
  const handlePasswordChange = (prop,value) =>  {
    Input = values[props]
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: {show:Input.show, 
    password:value} });
  };
  
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        marginLeft: "30%",
      }}
    >
      <h4>Change your password</h4>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
        Current password
      </InputLabel>
      <Input
        type={values.currentPassword.show ? "text" : "password"}
        onChange={({target})=>handlePasswordChange("currentPassword",target.value)}
        value={values.currentPassword.password}
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton
              onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
            >
              {values.currentPassword.show ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
            New password
        </InputLabel>
        <Input
            type={values.newPassword.show ? "text" : "password"}
            onChange={({target})=>handlePasswordChange("newPassword",target.value)}
            value={values.newPassword.password}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                >
                  {values.newPassword.show ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">
            Confirm password
        </InputLabel>
        <Input
            type={values.confirmPassword.show ? "text" : "password"}
            onChange={({target})=>handlePasswordChange("confirmPassword",target.value)}
            value={values.confirmPassword.password}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                >
                  {values.confirmPassword.show ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first solution there are a number of errors: currentPassword:{show:false,password:''}, and the missing arg to the function                                                             onClick={() => handleClickShowPassword('currentPassword')}.  It works then.